# Disqus comment box setup

Tags: javascript, multithreading, installation, dreamweaver, disqus

I am new to web building, and I am trying to set up disqus as a third party commenting system because they seem quite simple and the formatting is nice, I trying to set it up on dreamweaver CS6, but am lost as to how to set it up. These are the set up instructions on that come once I set up an account with them:

1. Place the following where you want disqus to load.

   /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
       var disqus_shortname = 'yoursite'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

   ```
   /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
   (function() {
       var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
       dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
       (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
   })();
   ```

   Please enable JavaScript to view the [comments powered by Disqus.](http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript)

   comments powered by Disqus

Now the rest of how to install it completely are here at this link: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-tightening-your-disqus-integration

The main thing I don't get is this "#disqus_thread" thing.

I am a first time web builder and have no idea what this all means, if someone could help me out that would be very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

div with id "disqus_thread" is a place where comments is showing up

This part is the most important, don't forget to register on [disqus](http://disqus.com/)

```
 var disqus_shortname = 'jsfiddles'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
```

here's example of using disqus

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mk_yo/8BDYj/5/)